# To use the :country input, please install a country_select plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activeadmin

I have a country attribute to my guidelines model.  I don't want to use a plugin, I just want to have country as a string. Everything is working until I try to edit a guideline in activeadmin and then I get the error message:

> ActionView::Template::Error (To use the :country input, please install
>   a country_select plugin, like this one:
>   https://github.com/jamesds/country-select):
>       1: insert_tag renderer_for(:edit)

in my form I have

```
 <%= f.input :country, as: :string%>
```

in my admin/guidelines.rb I have

```
index do                            
    column :title   
    column :specialty                
    column :content       
    column :hospital
    column :country   
    column :user
    default_actions                   
  end
```

Answer (score 20):

I'm not sure where you get this form code from but I had the same issue with Active Admin and resolved it by explicitly instructing the form to treat the field as a string:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Guideline do

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Details' do
      f.input :country, :as => :string
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

First you need to add the gem in GemFile

```
gem 'country-select'
```

Create a helper file '/app/helpers/active_admin/views_helper.rb'. Add the below code

```
module ActiveAdmin::ViewsHelper

  def country_dropdown 
    ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES
  end 
end
```

In your view file use

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do 
    f.input :country, as: :select, collection: country_dropdown
  end

  f.actions
end
```

Comment: She's explicitly stating that she doesn't want to use a plugin... -1

Answer (score 1):

Use [`country_select`](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select). Seems to work fine with Rails 4.1 if you're doing this recently. Plus Rails old repo links to this one rather than country-select.

Comment: This works great and has better features. For example to only show certain countries and I18n on by default.

Comment: She's explicitly stating that she doesn't want to use a plugin... -1

Answer (score 0):

You're using **ActiveAdmin**, so you're also using **Formtastic**.

In Formtastic, in the file *formtastic/lib/formtastic/inputs/country_input.rb* it clearly says:

```
# Rails doesn't come with a `country_select` helper by default any more, so you'll need to do
# one of the following:
#
# * install the [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) gem
# * install any other country_select plugin that behaves in a similar way
# * roll your own `country_select` helper with the same args and options as the Rails one
```

I would add `gem 'country-select'` to your **Gemfile** and do a **bundle install** as is the simplest and fastest solution.

Comment: She's explicitly stating that she doesn't want to use a plugin... -1

Comment: I didn't suggest a plugin she wasn't already using indirectly.

Comment: I'll agree this isn't necessarily the "best" answer, but it's extremely helpful by exposing the root cause of OP's question -- good for those of us who land here via related Google searches.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could install the gem, and then override the display in active_admin.

Answer (score -4):

I recommend you to use the `country-select`:

```
gem 'country-select'
```

I spent a lot of hours to find out why country-select is not working in my form :)

Comment: She's explicitly stating that she doesn't want to use a plugin... -1